Amplifier based on a bipolar transistor with a common emitter



I've done all the necessary calculations, but I don't understand what values I should set on the devices. Please help me

What do you mean by "what values I should set on the devices"? What devices?

Function generator, Bode Plotter, Oscilloscope

What you should set your test equipment to depends entirely on what you want to test, which you haven't made clear.

In Multisim, model a circuit for studying the AC voltage amplifier stage on a bipolar transistor using a common emitter circuit
Use the XFG1 function generator in the sinusoidal voltage generation mode as a source of input AC voltage for the stage under study.
Connect a two-channel oscilloscope XSC1 for simultaneous
to simultaneously monitor the signals at the input and output of the circuit.
Connect a frequency response and frequency frequency response analyzer (Bode Ploter XBP1) to the output poles of the cascade to study the frequency response parameters of the cascade.

Did you really intend to apply a 23MHz 10V peak waveform as an input signal from XFG1 function generator? You might try a smaller amplitude. Been a long time since I used Multisim...hazily recall that the function generator COM should go to GND instead of -...but I might be wrong.

@ioftenfeellonely The circuit you show is poor. At an input of only 10 mV peak, you will already see THD at 10%. At 30 mV peak it will be 25%. What's the goal?

Try with the values ​​calculated with my method. The voltage gain, not being known, was set to my liking (I apologize, there are some overlaps in the printout that disturb the reading):


Thank you very much!!! :) NihuNePon
